# Displaying multiple child-grandchild-relationships properly through Views

Tags: views, entities

I am using the most recent versions of Drupal (7.14), Views (3.3) and the Entity reference module (1.0 rc3).

I have three content types. The first of them (parent) contains a node reference field to the second (child), which has a node reference to the third (grandchild). Each of these reference fields have unlimited values.

I have set up a block view, with relationships for both node reference fields, and have defined a contextual filter for the parent node id.

This is what I want to display in the parent node, each with summaries and a few other fields from the referenced nodes:

```
Child 1
Grandchild 1
Grandchild 2
Grandchild 3

Child 2
Grandchild 4
Grandchild 5
```

With displaying an unformatted list of fields, I get the following result (aggregation doesn't help at all):

```
Child 1
Grandchild 1

Child 1
Grandchild 2

Child 1
Grandchild 3

Child 2
Grandchild 4

Child 2
Grandchild 5
```

Any suggestions for how I can get the display that I want?

Answer (score 2):

So you've tried going into your 'Settings' for the unformatted list style and setting a 'Grouping field' already?

If not, try the following, and make sure to check the box I've checked here as well:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a million! I had tried to work with that before, but now I fiddled with it a little more, and got it to work. :)

Here's what I did in addition to your tip:
1. Excluded all child node type's fields from display
2. Grouped like you instructed by each field of the child node type

Comment: Glad it worked!